# Does $P(e^a,e^b)=0$ imply $P=0$ if $e^{at}, e^{bt}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, independence

Let $\{a,b\}$ be linearly independent set over $\mathbb Q$ and $\{e^{at},e^{bt}\}$ be linearly independent set over $\mathbb Q[[t]]$. Suppose $P(x,y)$ is a polynomial over $\mathbb Q$.

> Does $P(e^a,e^b)=0$ imply $P=0$ ?

Suppose $P(x,y)=Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2 \in \mathbb Q[x,y]$. Then,
\begin{align}& P(e^a,e^b)=0 \\
\Rightarrow & Ae^{2a}+Be^{a+b}+Ce^{2b}=0  \end{align}

Can we conclude $A=B=C=0$ ?

Comment: @Kolja, I am not sure about the final conclusion. It seems true

Comment: Oops, that was a comment to a deleted comment :)